# How to achieve recyclerview with horizontal list but vertical scrolling android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve a design as in below screenshot,
[image: Example list design]

In this example screenshot, there are multiple list and also with scrolling.
Can we achieve this with recyclerview or is there any other way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recyclerview but if you want to do this in a quick way then use this library:

https://github.com/2dxgujun/AndroidTagGroup

How to use:

Add this on your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
}
```

Add this on your xml file:

```
<me.gujun.android.taggroup.TagGroup
    android:id="@+id/tag_group"
    style="@style/TagGroup" />
```

Add this on your java/kotlin file

```
TagGroup mTagGroup = (TagGroup) findViewById(R.id.tag_group);
mTagGroup.setTags(new String[]{"Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3"});
```